# Database Sharding with Concurrency Control And ACID Properties

Tags: concurrency, rdbms, sharding, distributed-system, acid

Lately, i've been reading about Database sharding and database concurrency control as well as ACID properties and i've been thinking about some scenarios that are a little bit tricky for me.

Suppose we want to have a transaction for money transfer from an Account to another. Suppose we have Customers (Accounts) sharded by Country, like US Customers on a specific server separated from European Customers (for the sake of scalability)

A transaction for such system should be something like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE FROM Account SET balance = balance - 100.0 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE FROM Account SET balance = balance + 100.0 WHERE id = 2;
COMMIT;
```

1- Suppose that Account #1 is from Europe and Account #2 is from US. How ACID properties are going to be kept in this situation ? because from an application we would have a different session with each shard (separated database servers) which means different transactions !

2- This might also be a problem in detecting deadlocks, how could we detect for example deadlocks in a concurrent application if the above transaction would get executed by 2 different thread in a different order !

I know that this can be easily done if we had only 1 database holding all the records as it have total control over the data, but in distributed databases, i believe we maybe do need some communication with different databases or maybe a central agent to handle such cases !

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post. PS What has your (web, textbook, manual & SO) research on sharding & distributed DBs shown? You haven't even applied the basic notions here, please don't ask for yet another presentation. [ask] [help] PS "ACID" is an appealing & popular vague & misleading way of (dis)organizing transaction notions, taken from the introduction of a famous paper that doesn't even use it & that introduction & the rest of the paper both make it clear that what matters is serializability of schedules.

Comment: It's not even clear what you are asking--eg how to call/program what DBMS functionality or how a DBMS implements what functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is consensus algorithm, so that account 1 and account 2 both can agree that $100 transaction happened between them.

This is pretty vast topic with people having PHDs only studying consensus algorithm.
List of famous consensus algorithms are:

1. Paxos
2. Raft
3. Two phase commit

I will start with 2 phase commit (simplest of all 3 above) if bar for extreme performance can be lowered a bit.

Comment: Awesome yeah thanks ! i've seen that it's a brand new topic and researches is being done on it, so interresting. Even postgresql recently released a distributed system mechanism in the newest versions. I believe this be a necessity in the futur once algorithms and techniques will be more available